# Looing for api.chm for solidworks 2018

Tags: solidworks

I just finished installing Solidworks 2018 premium but the software is not able to connect to the web help. Also, for API help, the software reports that the api help file named api.chm is missing in folder ../lang/english.

Can someone please provide a link to download api.cfm for Solidworks 2018?

Comment: What about contacting SolidWorks support?

Comment: Totally off-topic for SO. This is for programming questions.

Comment: Did you check this path?
C:\Program Files\SolidWorks Corp\SolidWorks\api\

Comment: Or try online help http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Welcome.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why it wasn't installed, but you can always find the api help online at http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Welcome.htm. In the upper right hand corner you can also change the version as needed too.

Answer (score 4):

Download [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ3wIU7ZLw1LLCpjaESjfwceh7sGoRfn2wOV) (2018, SP 4.0) or use the online API help.